# Regular Expressions Detecting Xbox controls

Tags: javascript, regex

I was trying many patterns to detect B button alone, but the patterns didn't work, or they also found RB and LB.
I've tried:

```
/B(?!^LB$|^RB$)/g
/^B$|^B,$|^ B,$/g
/^B$|^B,$|^ B,$(?!^LB$|^RB$)/g
```

The pattern should detect B alone, near a comma and/or space.

Comment: What information do you require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` and `$` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the search to the start and end of the entire input string, which is why (for example) `(?!^LB$|^RB$)` can never be true in your regexes.

You can probably solve the problem with [word boundary anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```
/\bB\b/
```

matches `B` only if there are no adjoining letters (or digits/underscore).

If you also need to ensure that an actual space or comma appear before or after your `B`, then use

```
/[ ,]B\b|\bB[ ,]/
```